# Cmake Error While Buliding Pixhawk simulator

Tags: quadcopter, simulation, gazebo, px4

I am trying to run "px4 SITL simulation" using gazebo7 on my machine with "UBUNTU-14.04 LTS" using these commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/PX4/Firmware.git
cd Firmware
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

But as I enter the next command i.e :

```
make posix_sitl_default gazebo
```

It gives an error -->

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/arpit/src/Firmware/build/posix_sitl_default/-Wno-deprecated" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/arpit/src/Firmware/build/posix_sitl_default 
make: *** [posix_sitl_default] Error 2
```

Any Solutions?

Comment: There might be a problem in the Makefile. Particularly, the fact that the build directory and one of the C flags are concatenated together. I would suggest checking out a certain tag (1.6.5 seems to be the latest?) and build that. You might have taken the code at some buggy in-development state.

Comment: I think you executing make command in the wrong directory, please go to build and execute make command, please let me know whether it works?

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the Makefile where this is breaking depending on your exact setup. As a quick fix I would hack out the -Wno-deprecated from the Makefile, and I'll look at fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a missing space in the makefile. the flag should be on a separate line from directories.
That is as far as I can say since I don't have the file.